# Finding The Least Integer Value

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

$\sqrt{x^{2}+9}+\sqrt{\left(y-x\right)^{2}+4}+\sqrt{\left(9-y\right)^{2}+49}$

*(x and y is not zero and different from each other.)*

How can I find the least integer value of that kinda expression above ? I would like to know that which topics I lack causing me stuck and suggestions for further studying.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @coffee, I don't see how any of those work. If $x=\pm4$ and $y=9\pm24=33{\rm or\ }-15$ you just don't get $y-x=\pm3$. Also, for the 2nd radical, I think you're reading $4$ as $4^2$. The question seems somewhat screwy to me. I think $x,y$ can't (both) be integers.

Comment: @coffee, that yields the sum $7+\sqrt{29}$, not an integer. Also, OP explicitly excludes both $x=0$, and $y=x$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson oops you were right before and i *was* reading the 4 as 4^2 in the second radical.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think all three radicals would need to be integers, for an integer sum. But that means $(y-x)^2+4$ is square, not possible given $x \neq y.$

Comment: @coffee, the sum is a continuous function of $x$ and $y$, so it should take on lots of integer values, mostly (or, entirely) when $x$, $y$, and $x-y$ are all transcendental. OP does not insist $x$ and $y$ be integers. I stand by my suggestion that the question is somewhat screwy.

Comment: Question which I consider relevant, that I do not know the answer to.  Suppose that $~A,B,C \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ such that the sum $\displaystyle ~\left[ ~\sqrt{A} + \sqrt{B} + \sqrt{C} ~\right]~$ is an integer.  Does this automatically imply that $~A,B,C~$ are all perfect squares?

Comment: @user2661923 After a few steps isolating a radical and squaring, get to $\sqrt{C}$ being rational.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A\equiv(0,0)$,$B\equiv(3,x)$,$C\equiv(5,y)$ and $D\equiv(12,9)$.

$\Rightarrow\sqrt{x^{2}+9}+\sqrt{\left(y-x\right)^{2}+4}+\sqrt{\left(9-y\right)^{2}+49}=AB+BC+CD\geq AD=\sqrt{12^2+9^2}=15$

Equality occurs if the points $A,B,C,D$ are collinear.

So, the least value of the given expression is **$15$** which happens to be an integer.

Equation of $AD$ is :$$Y=\frac{3}{4}X$$

So, for least value $x=\frac{9}{4}$ and $y=\frac{15}{4}$

Comment: Thanks a lot @Maverick, which topics I need to study to be proficient on that ? What are the things I lack made me stuck ?

Comment: I think the main thing we all lacked was Maverick's imagination. I hope this isn't a problem from some active competition.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I guess, I'm not that "all" you mentioned :d. By the way, I don't know where it comes from unfortunately. But, it's a multiple-choice question meaning that the probability of coming from active competition is not likely. (Also, I don't know what the answer is.)

Comment: But, now you do know what the answer is – Maverick has given you the answer, no? And it didn't use any mathematics more advanced than Analytic Geometry, not even Calculus.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yeah, it was. My emphasis was mathematical thinking behind the solution, not technical aspects, procedures or operations meaning that I simply didn't get why we define 4 points as like that. What's the idea behind it ?

Comment: That's where imagination comes in. You have to look at $\sqrt{x^2+9}$ and see it as the distance from the origin to $(3,x)$; then it follows that $\sqrt{(y-x)^2+4}$ is the distance from $(3,x)$ to $(5,y)$, and $\sqrt{(9-y)^2+49}$ is the distance from $(5,y)$ to $(12,9)$, so the sum you're being asked to minimize is the distance from $(0,0)$ to $(12,9)$, if you go by way of $(3,x)$ and $(5,y)$. And to minimize that distance, $(3,x)$ and $(5,y)$ have to be on the line from $(0,0)$ to $(12,9)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson that's so nice I appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mertallica The motivation of constructing such a problem was  probably to check whether student could apply the Distance formula which is the most basic idea of Analytic Geometry. You may accept the answer.

Comment: @Maverick Thanks for your feedback, it was really insightful. I got the taste. Appreciated much.

Comment: What user Maverick is suggesting, Mertallica, is that you can click in the check mark next to the answer to "accept" it. It's up to you.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I see.. I'm new in StackExchange need some time to get familiar with it. Thanks.